# AngularJS drag n drop treeview node to create grid

Tags: angularjs, treeview

For an example, please refer to the below screenshot :

[image]

AngularJS drag n drop treeview node to create grid

Comment: ![screeshot for Angular Treeview to grid][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XFGhS.png

Comment: I am new to Angular, please suggest with some references for :